# How to get content URI for Android 12 for document files(pdf, doc, word)?

Tags: android, android-file

**Sorry for the long post.**

I want to upload different types of files to our server from Android using API.

I am using the below code for file pick

```
Intent pickDocument = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
pickDocument.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
pickDocument.setType("*/*");
activity.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(pickDocument, "ChooseFile"), requestCode);
```

And I am using the below class to get the file path from URI.

```
public class UriUtils {
    private static Uri contentUri = null;
    private static MimeTypeMap mimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public static String getPathFromUri(final Context context, final Uri uri) {
        // check here to is it KITKAT or new version
        final boolean isKitKatOrAbove = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;
        String selection = null;
        String[] selectionArgs = null;

        // DocumentProvider
        if (isKitKatOrAbove && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {

            // ExternalStorageProvider
            if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                String fullPath = getPathFromExtSD(split);
                if (fullPath != "") {
                    return fullPath;
                } else {
                    return null;
                }
            } else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    final String id;
                    Cursor cursor = null;
                    try {
                        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[]{MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME}, null, null, null);
                        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                            String fileName = cursor.getString(0);
                            String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Download/" + fileName;
                            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(path)) {
                                return path;
                            }
                        }
                    } finally {
                        if (cursor != null)
                            cursor.close();
                    }
                    id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(id)) {
                        if (id.startsWith("raw:")) {
                            return id.replaceFirst("raw:", "");
                        }
                        String[] contentUriPrefixesToTry = new String[]{
                                "content://downloads/public_downloads",
                                "content://downloads/my_downloads"
                        };
                        for (String contentUriPrefix : contentUriPrefixesToTry) {
                            try {
                                final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Uri.parse(contentUriPrefix), Long.valueOf(id));
                                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
                            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                                //In Android 8 and Android P the id is not a number
                                return uri.getPath().replaceFirst("^/document/raw:", "").replaceFirst("^raw:", "");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                    if (id.startsWith("raw:")) {
                        return id.replaceFirst("raw:", "");
                    }
                    try {
                        contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                                Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));
                    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    if (contentUri != null) {
                        return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
                    }
                }
            } else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                selection = "_id=?";
                selectionArgs = new String[]{split[1]};

                Uri contentUri = null;
                if ("image".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } 

                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
            } else if (isGoogleDriveUri(uri)) {
                return getDriveFilePath(uri, context);
            }
        } else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri)) {
                return uri.getLastPathSegment();
            }
            if (isGoogleDriveUri(uri)) {
                return getDriveFilePath(uri, context);
            }
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                return getMediaFilePathForN(uri, context);
            } else {
                return copyFromSource(uri, context);
            }
        } else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            return uri.getPath();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static boolean fileExists(String filePath) {
        File file = new File(filePath);
        return file.exists();
    }

    private static String getPathFromExtSD(String[] pathData) {
        final String type = pathData[0];
        final String relativePath = "/" + pathData[1];
        String fullPath = "";

        if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
            fullPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + relativePath;
            if (fileExists(fullPath)) {
                return fullPath;
            }
        }

        fullPath = System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE") + relativePath;
        if (fileExists(fullPath)) {
            return fullPath;
        }

        fullPath = System.getenv("EXTERNAL_STORAGE") + relativePath;
        if (fileExists(fullPath)) {
            return fullPath;
        }

        return fullPath;
    }

    private static String getDriveFilePath(Uri uri, Context context) {
        Uri returnUri = uri;
        Cursor returnCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(returnUri, null, null, null, null);

        int nameIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
        int sizeIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.SIZE);
        returnCursor.moveToFirst();
        String name = (returnCursor.getString(nameIndex));
        String size = (Long.toString(returnCursor.getLong(sizeIndex)));
        File file = new File(context.getCacheDir(), name);
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            int read = 0;
            int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
            int bytesAvailable = inputStream.available();

            //int bufferSize = 1024;
            int bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            final byte[] buffers = new byte[bufferSize];
            while ((read = inputStream.read(buffers)) != -1) {
                outputStream.write(buffers, 0, read);
            }
            inputStream.close();
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return file.getPath();
    }

    private static String getMediaFilePathForN(Uri uri, Context context) {
        Uri returnUri = uri;
        Cursor returnCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(returnUri, null, null, null, null);

        int nameIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
        int sizeIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.SIZE);
        returnCursor.moveToFirst();
        String name = (returnCursor.getString(nameIndex));
        String size = (Long.toString(returnCursor.getLong(sizeIndex)));
        File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), name);
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            int read = 0;
            int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
            int bytesAvailable = inputStream.available();

            //int bufferSize = 1024;
            int bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            final byte[] buffers = new byte[bufferSize];
            while ((read = inputStream.read(buffers)) != -1) {
                outputStream.write(buffers, 0, read);
            }
            inputStream.close();
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return file.getPath();
    }


    private static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
        Cursor cursor = null;
        final String column = "_data";
        final String[] projection = {column};
        try {
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection,
                    selection, selectionArgs, null);

            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                final int index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
                return cursor.getString(index);
            }
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null)
                cursor.close();
        }

        return null;
    }

    private static String copyFromSource(Uri uri, Context context) {

        ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
        String fileExtension = getFileExtension(uri, contentResolver);

        String fileName = queryName(uri, contentResolver);
        if (fileName == null)
            fileName = getFileName(fileExtension);

        // the file which will be the new cached file
        File filePath = context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS);
        File outputFile = new File(filePath, fileName);
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
            int read = 0;
            int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
            int bytesAvailable = inputStream.available();

            //int bufferSize = 1024;
            int bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);

            final byte[] buffers = new byte[bufferSize];
            while ((read = inputStream.read(buffers)) != -1) {
                outputStream.write(buffers, 0, read);
            }
            inputStream.close();
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return outputFile.getAbsolutePath();
    }

    @SuppressLint("Recycle")
    private static String queryName(Uri uri, ContentResolver contentResolver) {
        Cursor returnCursor = contentResolver.query(uri, null, null, null, null);
        if (returnCursor == null)
            return null;

        int nameIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
        if (nameIndex == -1)
            return null;

        returnCursor.moveToFirst();
        String name = returnCursor.getString(nameIndex);
        returnCursor.close();
        return name;
    }

    private static String getFileExtension(Uri uri, ContentResolver contentResolver) {
        return mimeType.getExtensionFromMimeType(contentResolver.getType(uri));
    }

    private static String getFileName(String fileExtension) {
        return System.currentTimeMillis() + fileExtension + "";
    }

    private static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    private static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    private static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    private static boolean isGooglePhotosUri(Uri uri) {
        return "com.google.android.apps.photos.content".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    private static boolean isGoogleDriveUri(Uri uri) {
        return "com.google.android.apps.docs.storage".equals(uri.getAuthority()) || "com.google.android.apps.docs.storage.legacy".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }
}
```

This code is working fine in **Android 10** and below. But **I am getting issue in Android 12**

If I pick a file which is a **document(doc, pdf, excel, txt)** other than an image, video, and audio, I am getting **path null**.

In Android 12(Pixel 3), I got below URI

```
content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/document%3A27958
```

So according to the **above code**, this is **Media Document**.

```
private static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}
```

And If the file is media I am handling only 3 types of files

```
if ("image".equals(type)) {
        contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
} else if ("video".equals(type)) {
        contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
} else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
        contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
}
```

**How to get contentUri if there are document files(doc, excel, pdf, txt)?**

Comment: "And I am using the below class to get the file path from URI" -- delete that. "If I pick a file which is a document(doc, pdf, excel, txt) other than image, video, and audio, I am getting path null." -- you will fail for lots of `Uri` values, including on older versions of Android than 12. A `Uri` is not a file. There are plenty of sources of `Uri` values that will not map to a filesystem path, let alone a filesystem path that you can use. The selected content could be in Google Drive or another cloud storage provider, or on a network file server, or in an encrypted document store, etc.

Comment: I knew you will add your input @CommonsWare :).

I am spending time on this for over a week. If I remove the above that you have mentioned. How do get a proper file path for all Android versions and for all types of files i.e Image, Audio, Video, and other files?

Comment: "How do get a proper file path for all Android versions" -- you don't. To the greatest extent possible, you use the `Uri` as designed, such as via `openInputStream()`/`openOutputStream()` on `ContentResolver`. For cases where streams are insufficient (e.g., SQLite databases), you will need to make a copy of the content. You have code for that buried in the stuff in your question, but making a copy of the content has UX implications as well (e.g., import/export or backup/restore semantics).

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me.

```
   if ("image".equals(type)) {
       uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
   } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
       uri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
   } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
       uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
   }else if ("document".equals(type)) {
       uri = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external");
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save your **document files** in an temp folder and return its address.

For example, Telegram messenger stores these types of files in this path:

> Android\data\org.telegram.messenger\cache\sharing

**Example for your code:**

```
 String tempPath = getPathFromUri(context, uri);
 if (tempPath == null) {
   tempPath = MediaController.copyFileToCache(uri, "file");

   if (tempPath == null) {
     showAttachmentError();
     return;
   }
 }
```